# Laravel with() works only for first record (only for record with id 1)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

Imagin situation where in laravel User Eloquent model I have this kind of relationship functions:

```
public function serviceProvider(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Users\ServiceProvider');
}

public function company(){
    return $this->serviceProvider->company();
}
```

I have this kind of relationship in serviceProvider model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Http\Models\Companies\Company', 'companyable');
}
```

Now in controller I write something like that:

```
User::where('status', '=', 1)->with('company')->get();
```

I know it sounds crazy but it only works for record where user's `id = 1,` for the rest of the record it just returns `company : null`

I have no idea what is going on here, Maybe I am doing something wrong? what is the problem?

If I write something like that: `$user->company`, it works, It works for each user, I mean for

`$user = User::where('id', '=', "any id")->first;`

so problem is with `with()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little surprised this is working at all to be fair.

Since your `User` a relationship for `serviceProvider` set up and that has a relationship for `company` you don't need to have a `company` relationship in `User`.

If you want to eager/lazy load nested relationships you can just use dot notation e.g.

```
User::with('serviceProvider.company')->where('status', 1)->get();
```

[Lazy load docs (scroll down to **Nested Eager Loading**)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: @O.Shekriladze Glad I could help!

Comment: One last question, It gives me something like that:     
           
 "service_provider": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "company": {
                     }
}

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of service_provider? I just need company

Comment: @O.Shekriladze Not that I know of, you would still need to access it as `$user->serviceProvider->company`. Are you returning this in a JSON response?

Comment: @O.Shekriladze Something like: `$user->setAttribute('company', $slide->serviceProvider->company)->unsetRelation('serviceProvider');` should work.